# Checking separate variables with a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check 4 separate variables for the exact same strings using separate variables with similar names. An example is below. The print functions are also an example, they're not my final goal.

```
from random import randint
example1 = randint(1,3)
example2 = randint(1,3)
example3 = randint(1,3)
example4 = randint(1,3)
if example1 == 1:
  print ("A")
elif example1 == 2:
  print ("C")
else:
  print ("M")
```

Can anyone suggest how I could repeat this area for all of the variables?

```
if example1 == 1:
  print ("A")
elif example1 == 2:
  print ("C")
else:
  print ("M")
```

Comment: Please post real code. `randint(str(1,3))` gives a TypeError. What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: `randint(str(1,3))` will throw an error

Comment: `len({example1,example2,example3,example4}) == 1`?

Comment: As a general rule, when you have "separate variables with similar names" (and similar values and semantic), you really want a `list` or a `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `str` from `randint(str(1,3))`

```
l = [example1, example2, example2, example4]

for i in l:
    if i == 1:
      print ("A")
    elif i == 2:
      print ("C")
    else:
      print ("M")
```

or

```
[print('A') if i == 1 else print('C') if i ==2 else print('M') for i in l]
```

> ```
> C
> C
> C
> A
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
from random import randint
example1 = randint(1,3)
example2 = randint(1,3)
example3 = randint(1,3)
example4 = randint(1,3)
for example in (example1, example2, example3, example4):
  if example == 1:
    print ("A")
  elif example == 2:
    print ("C")
  else:
    print ("M")
```

The `(example1, example2, example3, example4)` part creates a [tuple](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-tuples) containing all of the four variables. The `for example in ...` part then repeats your desired code for each variable, with the `example` variable taking on the value of each different variable each time round the loop.

For more on for loops, you can take a look at the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: @JackTaylor `randint(str(1,3))` will thow an error as str can't be passed with more than 1 element

Comment: Thanks for the warning - should have tested that bit out first. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, just worded differently.

Answer (score 0):

A more scalable approach to your problem:

```
from random import randint
example1 = randint(1,3)
example2 = randint(1,3)
example3 = randint(1,3)
example4 = randint(1,3)

int_char_map = {1: "A", 2: "C", 3: "M"}

examples = [example1, example2, example2, example4]

print(examples)

for example in examples:
    print(int_char_map[example])
```